# How can I have the white section only show when a user is at the top of the page?

Tags: html, css

This is how I'm structuring my background I was wondering how to get it so that when the user scrolls the white at the top will match the blue. The white at the top should only show when they're at the top of the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<body>
<div id="bg-top"></div>
</body>
<style>

body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
}
#bg-top {
  background-color: #00b9ff;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  top: 12%;
  bottom: 6%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to give `#bg-top` a fixed `height` and `position:absolute` - flip your example

Start with a few browser default resets like so:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

You can then give `#bg-top` and `#bg-bottom` a white `background`

With position: absolute, `#bg-top` and `top:0` will not scroll with the content and will remain at the top of the page.

You can then make the `background-color` for the `body` into the blue color you want.

Same for `#bg-bottom` With `position: absolute`, and `bottom:0` it will not scroll with the content and will remain at the bottom of the page.

This can also be done with JS

Basic Pure CSS example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  background-color: #00b9ff;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  width: 20px;
}

#bg-top,
#bg-bottom {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1
}

#bg-top {
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
}

#bg-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="bg-top"></div>
  <p>scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll
    scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll
    scroll scroll scroll scroll scroll
  </p>
  <div id="bg-bottom"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That worked thank you! What about having the part at the bottom of the screen still white? It was divided into three sections.

Comment: Is it the same height as the top part? @HTMLHelp

Comment: #bg-top {
  background-color: #00b9ff;
  position: scrolling;
  top: 12%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 6%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  z-index: -1;
}

I just wanted it so the white at the top would scroll and when you get to the bottom the white at the bottom is still there.

Comment: I've edited my post so that You can see. I need the white at the top to go when you scroll down and the white at the bottom of the page to only be there when you get to the bottom of the page, I hope that's clearer :)

Comment: @HTMLHelp I edited the answer to reflect what I think you're going for. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I feel like I'm bugging you. The first piece of code you sent me does the same as that, with less lines. I'd like 12% of the top to be white and 6% of the bottom to be white and the rest the screen to be blue. Both sets you sent worked for the top white section to scroll away but there was no white at the bottom. I'd add a white footer but I need it in the background, thanks again :D